# Вырезать слово из html запроса

Tags: python, bs4

```
<h3 class="yt-lockup-title">
    <a aria-describedby="description-id-108408"
       class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link spf-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"
       data-sessionlink="ei=dBlLXefhEsWMyQXW4b2QAg&amp;feature=c4-videos-u&amp;ved=CB0Qlx4iEwjn65vpsvHjAhVFRrIKHdZwDyIomxw"
       dir="ltr"
       href="/watch?v=7428194"
       rel="nofollow"
       title=
```

Как правильно вырезать `watch?v=7428194` из html разметки выше?

```
s=requests.get('https://link')
b=bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
del b.find('h3').find('a')['href']
```

Или так, если надо удалить у заголовков определенного класса:

```
del b.find('h3', {'class': "yt-lockup-title"}).find('a')['href']
```

Или так, если надо "получить" значение, а не "вырезать" (удалить):

```
b.find('h3').find('a')['href']
```

Или так, если в заголовке много ссылок (тегов "а"):

```
for i in b.find('h3').findAll('a'):
    print(i['href'])
```

Надеюсь, что принцип понятен?